# calling a function secondarily causing different output in R

Tags: r, function

I have a function named `foo1` that works perfectly fine. However, when I simply call `foo1` using a second function `foo2`, it doesn't return the same output as `foo1` what am I missing (*really confused*)?

**see reproducible example below:**

```
foo1 <- function(data, cat.level = 0, code = NULL){

  cod <- if(is.numeric(code)) deparse(substitute(code)) else code

  mods <- c("genre","profic")

A <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(mods), function(i) table(data[[mods[i]]])), mods)
Ls <- lapply(A, length)

A <- A[Ls >= cat.level]

if(!is.null(code)){
target <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(i) any(names(A[[i]]) == cod))
A <- A[target]
}
return(A)
}
# EXAMPLE OF PERFECT USE:
d1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/v4.csv", h = T)#DATA

foo1(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)     # Works perfect! RETURNS A OF LIST TABLES
```

Now call `foo1` by `foo2`:

```
foo2 <- function(data, cat.level = 6, code = NULL){

  foo1(data = data, cat.level = cat.level, code = code) # simply call `foo1`
}

# EXAMPLE OF FAILURE:
foo2(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)
# > named list()                      # NOTHING RETURNS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `debug(foo1)` and then run it in isolation, you see that it is correctly finding `"77"`. I step through the lines below:

```r
debug(foo1)
foo1(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)
# debugging in: foo1(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)
# ...snip...
# debug at #2: cod <- if (is.numeric(code)) deparse(substitute(code)) else code
# debug at #2: deparse(substitute(code))
# debug at #3: mods <- c("genre", "profic")
cod
# [1] "77"
```

But if you debug it and run `foo2`, then see

```r
foo2(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)
# debugging in: foo1(data = data, cat.level = cat.level, code = code)
### ...snip...
# debug at #2: cod <- if (is.numeric(code)) deparse(substitute(code)) else code
# debug at #2: deparse(substitute(code))
# debug at #3: mods <- c("genre", "profic")
cod
# [1] "code"
```

which is obviously not what you want it to be. When you use `deparse(substitute(...))`, you will frequently (always?) have to assume this can happen.

I see no reason for you to use `deparse(substitute(code))` here. Try `as.character` instead:

```r
foo1 <- function(data, cat.level = 0, code = NULL){

  cod <- if(is.numeric(code)) as.character(code) else code

  mods <- c("genre","profic")

  A <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(mods), function(i) table(data[[mods[i]]])), mods)
  Ls <- lapply(A, length)

  A <- A[Ls >= cat.level]

  if(!is.null(code)){
    target <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(i) any(names(A[[i]]) == cod))
    A <- A[target]
  }
  return(A)
}
```

It works:

```r
foo1(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)     
# $genre
#  2  5  6  7 77 99 
# 65 93 57 14 24  4 
# $profic
#   0   1   2  77  99 
#  23 180  18  14  22 

foo2(d1, cat.level = 0, code = 77)
# $genre
#  2  5  6  7 77 99 
# 65 93 57 14 24  4 
# $profic
#   0   1   2  77  99 
#  23 180  18  14  22
```

Further, I believe you can omit that check/step entirely, for a few reasons.

1. `as.character` on a `character` is effectively a no-op, so no risk.
2. any comparisons between strings and `numeric` will convert the numbers to strings with an implicit cast/coercion.

So you can remove it entirely, as in:

```r
foo1 <- function(data, cat.level = 0, code = NULL){

  mods <- c("genre","profic")

  A <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(mods), function(i) table(data[[mods[i]]])), mods)
  Ls <- lapply(A, length)

  A <- A[Ls >= cat.level]

  if(!is.null(code)){
    target <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(i) any(names(A[[i]]) == code))
    A <- A[target]
  }
  return(A)
}
```

If you have concerns that some other object might be sent (`factor`, `logical`, etc), then you have other checks you can do.